# How do I "flush" a TCP Client Buffer?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, flush, asyncsocket

I've pulled from several examples to setup a Full Duplex C# TCP Client connected to a server.  The basic concept is that the client and server both send/receive messages (commands and events).   Therefore, I've developed a FullDuplexSocket class that exposes a Send method to send messages to the server and a event handler to receive messages from the server.    Everything works except I can't seem to flush the buffer of messages received from the server.  Each time the server sends a new message, the buffer in my socket contains all the old messages (already read) *and* the new message(s).   I could split the messages by a known delimiter (/r/n) and keep track of them, but this will likely be the source of memory issues on long running communications. [Edit:  Updated the code to a solution that no longer has buffer issues and works correctly].

Does anyone have any suggestions.  Total rewrite???  Code is below in hope that it will help others.

Here's the FullDuplexSocket class:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Utilities
{
    public class StateObject{
        public Socket workSocket = null;
        public const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    }

    public class FullDuplexSocket : IDisposable
    {
        public event NewMessageHandler OnMessageReceived;
        public delegate void NewMessageHandler(string Message);
        public event DisconnectHandler OnDisconnect;
        public delegate void DisconnectHandler(string Reason);

        private Socket _socket;
        private bool _useASCII = true;
        private string _remoteServerIp = "";
        private int _port = 0;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructer of a full duplex client socket.   The consumer should immedately define 
        /// and event handler for the OnMessageReceived event after construction has completed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="RemoteServerIp">The remote Ip address of the server.</param>
        /// <param name="Port">The port that will used to transfer/receive messages to/from the remote IP.</param>
        /// <param name="UseASCII">The character type to encode/decode messages.  Defaulted to use ASCII, but setting the value to false will encode/decode messages in UNICODE.</param>
        public FullDuplexSocket(string RemoteServerIp, int Port, bool UseASCII = true)
        {
            _useASCII = UseASCII;
            _remoteServerIp = RemoteServerIp;
            _port = Port;

            try //to create the socket and connect
            {
                _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                _socket.Connect(RemoteServerIp, _port);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to connect to the remote Ip.", e);
            }

            try //to listen to the socket
            {
                StateObject stateObject = new StateObject();
                stateObject.workSocket = _socket;

                _socket.BeginReceive
                    (
                        stateObject.buffer, //Buffer to load in our state object
                        0, //Start at the first position in the byte array
                        StateObject.BUFFER_SIZE, //only load up to the max per read
                        0, //Set socket flags here if necessary 
                        new AsyncCallback(ReadFromSocket), //Who to call when data arrives
                        stateObject //state object to use when data arrives
                    );
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to start listening to the socket.", e);
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// This will read the bytes from the socket, convert the bytes to a string and fire the OnMessageReceived event.
        /// If the socket is forcibly closed, the OnDisconnect event will be fired.   This happens when the other side of
        /// the socket connection on the remote Ip is no longer available.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="asyncResult"></param>
        public void ReadFromSocket(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            StateObject stateObject = (StateObject)asyncResult.AsyncState; //pull out the state object
            int bytesReceived = 0;

            try //to receive the message.
            {
                bytesReceived = stateObject.workSocket.EndReceive(asyncResult); 
            }
            catch (Exception e)  //Exception will occur if connection was forcibly closed.
            {
                RaiseOnDisconnect(e.Message);
                return;
            }

            if (bytesReceived > 0)
            {
                RaiseOnMessageReceived
                    (
                        _useASCII ?
                            Encoding.ASCII.GetString(stateObject.buffer, 0, bytesReceived) :
                            Encoding.Unicode.GetString(stateObject.buffer, 0, bytesReceived)
                    );

                stateObject.workSocket.BeginReceive
                    (
                        stateObject.buffer, //Buffer to load in our state object
                        0, //Start at the first position in the byte array
                        StateObject.BUFFER_SIZE, //only load up to the max per read
                        0, //Set socket flags here if necessary 
                        new AsyncCallback(ReadFromSocket), //Who to call when data arrives
                        stateObject //state object to use when data arrives
                    );

            }
            else
            {
                stateObject.workSocket.Close();
                RaiseOnDisconnect("Socket closed normally.");
                return;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Broadcast a message to the IP/Port.  Consumer should handle any exceptions thrown by the socket.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Message">The message to be sent will be encoded using the character set defined during construction.</param>
        public void Send(string Message)
        {
            //all messages are terminated with /r/n
            Message += Environment.NewLine;

            byte[] bytesToSend = _useASCII ?
                Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Message) :
                Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Message);

            int bytesSent = _socket.Send(bytesToSend);

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up the socket.
        /// </summary>
        void IDisposable.Dispose()
        {
            try
            {
                _socket.Close();
                RaiseOnDisconnect("Socket closed via Dispose method.");
            }
            catch { }
            try
            {
                _socket.Dispose();
            }
            catch { }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// This method will gracefully raise any delegated events if they exist.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Message"></param>
        private void RaiseOnMessageReceived(string Message)
        {
            try //to raise delegates
            {
                OnMessageReceived(Message);
            }
            catch { } //when none exist ignore the Object Reference Error
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method will gracefully raise any delegated events if they exist.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Message"></param>
        private void RaiseOnDisconnect(string Message)
        {
            try //to raise delegates
            {
                OnDisconnect(Message);
            }
            catch { } //when none exist ignore the Object Reference Error
        }

    }
}
```

The consumer of the class would simply do the following:

```
using System;

namespace Utilities
{
    public class SocketConsumer
    {
        private FullDuplexSocket _fds;

        public Consumer()
        {
            _fds = new FullDuplexSocket("192.168.1.103", 4555);

            _fds.OnMessageReceived += fds_OnMessageReceived;

            _fds.Send("Hello World!");
        }

        void fds_OnMessageReceived(string Message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `OnMessageReceived` even if the buffer has not been filled (in case `bytesRead < count`). Consider switching to `await` for the async part of the application. That gets rid of the hideous callback recursion.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Stepping through the code, the count seems to be set to 1029990765 and is always greater than bytesRead.   Not clear on the use of await here, maybe an example might help?  Maybe I've got some logic backward?

Comment: Not sure what's going on there, but why is count equal to ~1 billion? That's a bug. Add a runtime assert to catch the earliest case where that condition is occurring.; await fill not immediately fix the problem - it will simplify the code drastically though (no callbacks at all) so the bugs will become obvious. I'm also hesitant to invest more time into this spaghetti mess of callbacks. It's not your fault - it's just the nature of callback-driven code.

Comment: After several iterations, I edited the code in the question to a workable solution.  The buffer is cleared after each message is received from the remote server and all is well.   I could not determine a method of using Async/await to solve this problem, so the ugly callback still exists, but appears to be correctly used given .NET's implementation of the Socket class.  Any other comments/alternative solutions are welcome.  ...Thanks usr...