# Flush the TCP receive data buffer?

Tags: c, winsock, tcpclient, winsock2

I am doing a program with Winsock to create a client and send data to a server in response to which server replies with a specific data block received, this is continued a number of times.

The problem is some times my data block 1 gets overlapped with data block 2 so I want to flush out my TCP reception buffer after the 1st complete reception.

I reffered to this link also [How do I "flush" a TCP Client Buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454634/how-do-i-flush-a-tcp-client-buffer) but I cant wait till the reception occurs

**How can I flush the TCP receive data buffer?**
I am doing my project in visual c++

Comment: With TCP, the data should arrive in the correct order. And if not, why empty the buffer (throwing the first part of packet2 away)? Or do you want to omit the next x bytes even if they are not here yet? Not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to "flush" the receive buffer is to read from it.  After the first read, keep reading from the socket, throwing that data away, until there is no more data available to read. Use `select()` with a timeout to detect when the socket is still receiving data.

If data is being "overlapped" then either the server is not sending the data correctly on its end (overlapping `send()` calls), or you are not reading the data correctly on your end.

Comment: You can also use recv( sock, buf, sizeof(buf), MSG_DONTWAIT ), but yes, this shouldn't come up.

Comment: `MSG_DONTWAIT` is not available on Windows.